# Moq verify method fails even though method will be called

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have some troubles using Moq. Following unit test throws an exception, even though the according method will be called.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CreateFinishTest() {
    // mock methods 
    factoryMock.Setup(f => f.LoadPlan("TestPlanDoNotUse")).Returns(testPlan).Verifiable();
    factoryMock.Setup(f => f.CreateFinish(It.IsAny<CreateFinishMessage>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(testFinish.Id).Verifiable();

    try {
        var cfm = new CreateFinishMessage() {
            ClientId = 11,
            MessageId = 23456,
            CustomerId = 6,
            FinishName = "MyFinish",
            PlanId = "TestPlanDoNotUse"
        };
        var cmd = sysCfg.Executor.CreateFinish(cfm); // calls LoadPlan with cfm.PlanId and CreateFinish with cfm and cfm.PlanId
        sysCfg.Executor.Execute(cmd);

        factoryMock.Verify(f => f.LoadPlan("TestPlanDoNotUse"), Times.Exactly(1));
        factoryMock.Verify(f => f.CreateFinish(It.IsAny<CreateFinishMessage>(), It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Exactly(1));
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        Assert.Fail(exc.Message);
    }
}
```

This Error occurs:

```
Expected invocation on the mock exactly 1 times, but was 0 times: f => f.LoadPlan("TestPlanDoNotUse")

Configured setups:
f => f.LoadPlan("TestPlanDoNotUse"), Times.Once

Performed invocations:
IFactory.LoadPlan("TestPlanDoNotUse")
Factory.CreateFinish(IndiValue.LiveMarket.IndiCore.Communication.MessagingFormat.CreateFinishMessage, "MyFinish")
```

I've tried several different Verify-Calls but it won't work. And the Error which occurs seems quite confusing it's says that `LoadPlan("TestPlanDoNotUse")` is never called, but it's listed @ Performed invocations.

Problem solved:

I think i found the problem, it wasn't a Moq problem. In `sysCfg.Executor.CreateFinish(cfm)` a new thread was created and started. This thread wasn't finished and so  `factoryMock.Verify(...)` failed.

I used AutoResetEvents:

```
// create AutoResetEvent triggers
AutoResetEvent m_testTrigger1 = new AutoResetEvent(false);

// mock methods     
factoryMock.Setup(f => f.LoadPlan(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(testPlan).Callback(() => m_testTrigger1.Set());

// do something

// wait for triggers
bool didReturn1 = m_testTrigger1.WaitOne(timeOut);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the Verifiable not being called, it's important that the arguments in your expectation match the arguments that are being used by the production code.

Regarding the use of *Thread.Sleep*, avoid it wherever possible as it will only slow down the tests to meet your slowest machine.  I typically introduce WaitHandles into my tests to ensure that the tests run as fast as the code.

Take a [peek here on a small utility](http://www.bryancook.net/2011/04/testing-asynchronous-logic.html) that uses WaitHandles with events.

Answer (score 6):

You do not usually use Verifiable() in your setups in conjuction with the Verify(expr, times) methods. Does it work if you remove the .Verifiable() calls?

Comment: if i remove the .Verifiable() calls i get following error:    `Expected invocation on the mock exactly 1 times, but was 0 times: f => f.CreateFinish(It.IsAny<CreateFinishMessage>(), It.IsAny<String>())

Configured setups:
f => f.CreateFinish(It.IsAny<CreateFinishMessage>(), It.IsAny<String>()), Times.Never

Performed invocations:
IFactory.LoadPlan("TestPlanDoNotUse")`

Comment: That looks a little better, if that is indeed the whole error message. Now it looks like CreateFinish just doesn't get called. Does it say anything about performed invocations for CreateFinish?

Comment: No it didn't say anything about the invoaction of CreateFinish, but i debugged it through and i think i found the problem: see my answer. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is a me-too answer, but I believe this to be a simpler solution than many of the mentioned before.

I implemented a WaitFor function  which utilizes a lambda callback to evaluate a condition:

`public static void WaitFor(Func<bool> action, long timeoutMillis = 10000)
        {
            Stopwatch elapsed = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            elapsed.Start();
            // ReSharper disable once LoopVariableIsNeverChangedInsideLoop
            while (!action())
            {
                if (elapsed.ElapsedMilliseconds > timeoutMillis)
                {
                    throw new TimeoutException("Timed out waiting for condition to become true after " + elapsed.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
                }
                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
        }`

and the test code looks like this:

```
    [Test]
    public void ShouldNackUnparsableInboundMessage()
    {   
        var nackCalled = false;
        _mock.Setup(m => m.BasicNack(999, false, false)).Callback(() =>
        {
            nackCalled = true;
        });

        ... do whatever which invokes the call on another thread.

        WaitFor(() => nackCalled);
        // Test will fail with timeout if BasicNack is never called.
    }
```